# Intel's python + NumPy distro slower than locally-compiled with gcc on Linux

Tags: python-3.x, performance, numpy, intel, intel-mkl

I develop a numerical program for electricity calculations. One of the simulations uses many sparse linear systems solve calls.

I decided to test a python distro compiled on my pc with `gcc -O2` and downloading the packages with pip vs. python compiled by Intel with Intel's compiler, MKL and all the bells and whistles.

In the program I noticed that the python distro from Intel was slower, so I decided to make a test:

```
import scipy.sparse as sp
from scipy.sparse.linalg import spsolve
import numpy as np
import time
start = time.time()

repetitions = 50
n = 1000
np.random.seed(0)
for r in range(repetitions):
    A = sp.csr_matrix(sp.rand(n, n, 0.01))
    b = np.random.rand(n)
    x = spsolve(A, b)

end = time.time()
dt = end - start
print('total', dt, 's, average:', dt/repetitions, 's')
```

> Regular distro compiled by me:
>
> total 7.1154210567474365 s, average: 0.14230842113494874 s
>
> Intel python distro:
>
> total 7.645046949386597 s, average: 0.15290093898773194 s

This is, the regular numpy and scipy on a regular python on Linux is a 7% faster than the supposedly highly optimised intel-compiled scipy and numpy in the distro that they provide.

So my question is, how can this be?

So far my conclusion is that on Linux (Ubuntu 18.04) the standard python is faster than Intel's python.  And/or standard NumPy & SciPy is faster than Intel's NumPy & SciPy.

My CPU is an Intel i5.

EDIT: Added the result of `np.show_config()` in both cases:

```
blas_mkl_info:   NOT AVAILABLE 
blis_info:   NOT AVAILABLE 
openblas_info:
    libraries = ['openblas', 'openblas']
    library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
    language = c
    define_macros = [('HAVE_CBLAS', None)] 
blas_opt_info:
    libraries = ['openblas', 'openblas']
    library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
    language = c
    define_macros = [('HAVE_CBLAS', None)] 
lapack_mkl_info:   NOT AVAILABLE 
openblas_lapack_info:
    libraries = ['openblas', 'openblas']
    library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
    language = c
    define_macros = [('HAVE_CBLAS', None)] 
lapack_opt_info:
    libraries = ['openblas', 'openblas']
    library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
    language = c
    define_macros = [('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
```

And for intel's distro:

```
mkl_info:
    libraries = ['mkl_rt', 'pthread']
    library_dirs = ['/home/santi/Descargas/intelpython3/lib']
    define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    include_dirs = ['/home/santi/Descargas/intelpython3/include'] 
blas_mkl_info:
    libraries = ['mkl_rt', 'pthread']
    library_dirs = ['/home/santi/Descargas/intelpython3/lib']
    define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    include_dirs = ['/home/santi/Descargas/intelpython3/include'] 
blas_opt_info:
    libraries = ['mkl_rt', 'pthread']
    library_dirs = ['/home/santi/Descargas/intelpython3/lib']
    define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    include_dirs = ['/home/santi/Descargas/intelpython3/include'] 
lapack_mkl_info:
    libraries = ['mkl_rt', 'pthread']
    library_dirs = ['/home/santi/Descargas/intelpython3/lib']
    define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    include_dirs = ['/home/santi/Descargas/intelpython3/include'] 
lapack_opt_info:
    libraries = ['mkl_rt', 'pthread']
    library_dirs = ['/home/santi/Descargas/intelpython3/lib']
    define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    include_dirs = ['/home/santi/Descargas/intelpython3/include']
```

Comment: Is "standard Python faster than Intel's Python" or are "standard NumPy & SciPy faster than Intel's NumPy & SciPy"? Also, are you sure you're running an Intel CPU?

Comment: Absolutely, I'm on an i5, I guess the second statement is the one:  "standard NumPy & SciPy faster than Intel's NumPy & SciPy"

Comment: It might be helpful to post `np.show_config()` for both Python installations.

Comment: Are both versions using 64-bit builds of Python / NumPy?  If you have a 32-bit build of Intel software, it can only use 8 XMM/YMM registers which limits the amount of unrolling / software pipelining possible.

Comment: Yes, both are x64. Checking with `sys.maxsize > 0x100000000` returns True.

Comment: Did you do pip installs for mkl-fft and mkl-random as described in the installation doc from Intel?  https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/installing-the-intel-distribution-for-python-and-intel-performance-libraries-with-pip-and

Comment: Those two packages are not used in the test, and at intel's distro they should come installed by default